# Can not create 1:1 relation using EF because of difference in primary key data types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are using EF on the project and need to create 1:1 relation between 2 tables in the database (**FundMaterList** and **FundMeta**).

The first (**FundMasterList**) was created using db first approach and it has the following column as primary key :

`[PerformanceID] [char](10) NOT NULL`

and this primary constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_FundMasterList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([PerformanceID] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Second (**FundMeta**) was created using code-first approach and has the following declaration:

```
public class FundMeta
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Column("PerformanceID")]
    public string InstId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and the following mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FundMetadataEntity>()
                .Property(e => e.InstId)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<FundEntity>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.FundMeta)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Fund)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

FundMeta and Fund are declared as virtuals. When I am running database update I get the following error message:

*Column 'dbo.FundMasterList.PerformanceID' is not the same data type as referencing column 'FundMetadats.PerformanceID' in foreign key 'FK_dbo.FundMetas_dbo.FundMasterList_PerformanceID'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*

When I remove creating relations everithing works fine and column in the table FundMeta has the same type as in FundMasterList. It seems that creating relation try to "overwrite" this constraint:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FundMetadataEntity>()
                    .Property(e => e.InstId)
                    .IsFixedLength()
                    .IsUnicode(false);
```

**EDIT:**

When I generated migration script I've noticed the following changes:

Without relation it looks OK:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.FundMeta", "PerformanceID",
 c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10, fixedLength: true, unicode: false));
```

After the relationship added:

```
 DropPrimaryKey("dbo.FundMeta");
 AlterColumn("dbo.FundMeta", "PerformanceID", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10));
 AddPrimaryKey("dbo.FundMeta", "PerformanceID");
```

It means that limitation on `fixedLength: true, unicode: false` was lost.

When add this limitation manually in migration script everything works fine. Any other solutions possible?

Comment: True 1:1 relationships are nearly impossible in most databases since you can't insert to multiple tables at the same time. If you try to insert to one it will fail since there isn't a matching row in the other.  You generally have to model it as a 1:0,1 and validate the data after the fact.

Comment: Try adding .HasMaxLength(10) or force the char type .HasColumnType("char") How is it defining the key on FundMetadats? Since you are already using fluent, I would do all the configuration there ColumnName, string length, etc.

Comment: Have you tried Steve Solution ?

Comment: @tschmit007 Yes. I've tried but adding relationship brakes this settings (see updates for the question).

Answer (score 1):

Steve is true.

With no other information String leads to nvarchar.

So you are trying to create a constraint between char[10] and nvarchar[10].

You have to force the type of your PK by using `HasColumnType("char")` as stated by Steve.

NotUnicode may not be enough as you will get `varchar(10)`

Comment: I've tested your solution but it still doesn't work when I create relationship between **FundMasterList** and **FundMeta**. When I generated migration script I've noticed the following

`AlterColumn("dbo.FundMetadataEntities", "PerformanceID", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10));`


although in the previos script it was:

`AlterColumn("dbo.FundMetadataEntities", "PerformanceID", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10, fixedLength: true, unicode: false));`

It seems that EF does not support both changes (column limitation for char(10) and foreign key on this column)